# jspm / jQuery / TypeScript - module "jquery" has no default export

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I'm trying to bootstrap a web app using TypeScript and jspm & system.js for module loading. I'm not getting very far. After installing jspm, and using it to install jQuery:

```
jspm install jquery
```

And the basics:

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
        System.import('main');
</script>
```

main.ts:

```
import $ from "jquery";

export class Application  {
    constructor() {
        console.log($);
    }
}
```

The TypeScript won't compile because "Module 'jquery' has no default export.

The generated config.js has the correct mapping:  "jquery": "npm:jquery@2.2.0"

Comment: Did you tried `import * as $ from "jquery";`?

Comment: Thanks that works! If you submit that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When the module doesn't have a default export, you can import the complete module as object: `import * as $ from "jquery";`

or import named exports:
`import { ajax, css } from "jquery";`

Comment: Named exports doesn't work. Module jquery has no exported member 'css'.

Comment: Do not forget run: npm install jquery.

Comment: If the exported module is in CommonJS /AMD/UMD format (single exported member) the TypeScript documentation states you should use `import $ = require("jquery");` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require
Is there an advantage to either method?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `visual studio`, update the typescript plugin.

To obtain the latest version for visual studio 2017, [go there](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-272-vs2017)