# $ is not defined using JQuery in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

all
I'm making a small web app using Angular 2 and i want to use JQuery in it.
I'm getting a error in chrome I don't know why
Here is the error:

```
   core.umd.js:3004 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in `enter code here`http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js class DashboardComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: $ is not defined
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at DashboardComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:3000/app/dashboard.component.js:22:9)
    at Wrapper_DashboardComponent.detectChangesInInputProps (/AppModule/DashboardComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:18:53)
    at _View_DashboardComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/DashboardComponent/host.ngfactory.js:30:32)
    at _View_DashboardComponent_Host0.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
    at _View_DashboardComponent_Host0.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:48)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7398:24)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3458:46)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2955:20)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2933:26)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2902:23)
```

And here is my code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:JQueryStatic;
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef){}

    ngOnInit():any{
        $(this.elRef.nativeElement).find('button').on('click', function() {
           alert('It works!');
        });
    }
}
```

I used this answer to install jquery and did everything as explained but does not work.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623825/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular2)
Any ideas why?
Thanks

---

**FIX**
I fixed it by changing `declare var $:JQueryStatic;` to `declare var $:any;`
and included `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>` into `index.html`

Comment: Have you tried something like `import $ from 'jquery';`?

Comment: @DanielD I did just now, it says that `Module "jquery" has no default export.`

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223977/jspm-jquery-typescript-module-jquery-has-no-default-export

Comment: This depends on what version of typescript you are using.  I think they've moved away from requiring typings.  Your issue may be similar to the other question you linked to, but the answer depends on your versions of technologies.

Answer (score 1):

use the cdn on layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check if `jquery.js`is actually loaded using the chrome developer tools for example. If it does not, then you are missing a dependency in your module loader configuration.

You have to make sure the jquery.js dependency is known to the module loader of choice.

Comment: Okay, I have it in `package.jason` declared as `"jquery": "^3.1.1"` should I install it in some way?

Comment: @JakubBadacz where did you start from? can you share your code? it is hard to guess your actual setup ;)

Comment: it's okay, i figured it out :)

Comment: You basically did manually what I wanted you to do via the module loader of choice :) glad it works for you know, but I strongly recommend also searching for the module loader solution. It will help you once you add more dependencies and end up in a more complex sec scenario